# How can I validate the sub folders (Thats name will vary) which I need to pass into a hard coded path to run a File.Exists

Tags: c#, filepath

My requirement is I have a main folder under which has a set of subfolder. These subfolders are EXPECTED to have a "FileServer.config" file. I need to validate this and Out put a message if the File is missing.

MainFolder--> Contains subfolder 1 ,sub folder 02 , subfolder 03.

So when the user clicks say for example SubFolder01 I want t validate if this file exist in that folder

Currently in the Code I have the code scans for all the folders at once and the output is based on the first folder

```
string path =@ "D:\TEST\PROJ\Repo\";
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();

foreach(DirectoryInfo folder in subDirectories)
{
   string subpath = Path.Combine( @ "D:\TEST\PROJ\Repo\", folder.Name);
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(subpath, "fileserver.config");
   if(filePaths.Any())
   Console.WriteLine(subpath);
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada  I want to validate if the fileserver.cofig file exists in the subfolder that the user clicks

Comment: That is not a question... that is a requirement

Comment: Yeah Question is how to do that ? any suggested way ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
string path = @"D:\TEST\PROJ\Repo\";
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directory.GetDirectories())
{
    var files = folder.GetFiles("fileserver.config");

    if (files.Length > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
}
```

Comment: Still the same result. The loop checks into all sub directories at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You said the user clicks on a subdirectory (element), so I assume that you get a concrete folder path. To validate if a certain file is existing in a specific folder try

```
public bool FileExistsInFolder(string folderPath, string filename)
{
   return Directory.Exists(folderPath) 
          && Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, fileName).Any();
}
```